# Show spectrum for operator $S$ and $T$ coincide given that there is some $R$ s.t $T=R^{-1} S R$

Tags: functional-analysis

Im really stuck on the following excersice in functional analysis.

Show spectrum for operator $S$ on some Banach space $Y$ and $T$ on $X$ coincide given that there is some inverable $R$ s.t $T=R^{-1} S R$.

Im thinking bounded inverse theorem in some way might help but without any luck.
Could I get some hits please?

Comment: Compare the resolvents of $S$ and $T$. What can you say about the resolvent sets.

Comment: @A.G. I did im kinda stuck on that fact that I cant act on an element from the left. I.e xR is not allowed imo.

Comment: You do not need acting from the left because resolvents, resolvent sets and inverses are defined completely in terms of right-acting operators.

Comment: @A.G. acting on the right only helps me get that    $(\lambda R-S)R$ has same spectrum but I cant manage to get rid of $R$ on the  right by means of allowed operations.

Comment: Use the hint below to prove that $\lambda I-T$ invertible iff $\lambda I-S$ invertible. Then use the definition of the resolvent set and the spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\lambda I - T=R^{-1}(\lambda I-S)R$